# Can i reuse a water string filter with a backflush and vinegar flush

Tags: water, well, water-softener

Water here is very hard. String filter is caked up after 3 weeks.  Thinking backflush and wash with vinegar, reuse one time.  The new filters are 4.5 inch and at replacing every 3 weeks, thats going to get expensive.

Comment: The string filters I purchase are not very expensive , yes vinegar may dissolve some of the buildup but i would not want vinegar in my filter either.  I wonder if hydrogen peroxide would dissolve it ? That breaks down into water and oxygen. I use hydrogen peroxide for sanitation and killing mold , purchase 30+ % and dilute with water I don’t know if that would work or be cheaper in the long run. But it would be easier to flush out than vinegar I think.

Comment: hydrogen peroxide won't break up mineral deposits, but soda water will.

Comment: I'll post a pic of the filter when its changed - problem mostly solved though, local tractor supply has culligan 4.5 inch filters for $10.99.  Thats acceptable.  What I think is happening is the filter is precipitating the TDS.  Yes, owner needs a softener badly...But that still will be after the filter.  Thanks ALL!

Answer (score 2):

I think that you would be better served by a water conditioning company. When I moved into my new house 42 years ago I had a similar problem and I tried to correct the problem myself. When they failed I called "Culligan" who was the best company in my area at that time. A great gentleman came and tested my water. He recommended a solution that I thought was very expensive. I called a couple other companies but they were all reluctant to sell me anything. The guy from Culligan  solved my problem. That man stated that my water condition was the worst that he had ever seen. 20 years I sold that house and the system still worked well with a minimum of service calls. I am glad that I called in a professional.  my 2 cents

Comment: Agreed d.george. It sounds like the OP has a couple of things going on.  Usually hard water means lots of TDS (total dissolved solids) which are ions at that point and can't be filtered out by media because they are dissolved.  It sounds like the OP also has undissolved particles that could be filtered out, but that doesn't soften the water.  I agree the OP needs a pro here to properly sort this out.